# VueJS + Rest API list rendering issue

Tags: vue.js

I have a Spring Data Rest backend and in src/main/resources/static html + js assets which work fine. My issue is that I can't understand how to render the data picked up from the webservice in the interface.

In case I set the data explicitly as an array, it works fine (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html).

Thank you in advance!

```
...
const ListFormsApi = {
  template: '<div><ul><li v-for=\'item in items\'>{{item.details.Title}}</li></ul></div>',
  data: function(){
    return {
      items: ''
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.get()
  },
  methods: {
    get: function() {
      axiosInstance.get('/contactTemplate')
        .then(function (response) {
          this.items = response.data._embedded.contactTemplate
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
...
```

The webpage is quite simple and straightforward from documentation examples (assume that complete html and head tags are present as well...

```
    <body>

    <div id="app">
      <h1><router-link to="/">ContactForm Factory!</router-link></h1>
      <p>
        <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
        <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
        <router-link to="/listForms">List Forms</router-link>
        <router-link to="/listFormsApi">List Forms API</router-link>
      </p>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
                
    </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is happening because scope of this is not what you are expecting inside the `then` block of `axiosInstance`, you need to make following change to make it work.

```
methods: {
  get: function() {
    var self = this
    axiosInstance.get('/contactTemplate')
      .then(function (response) {
        self.items = response.data._embedded.contactTemplate
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    );
  }
```

You can have a look at my answer on the similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882183/1610034).

Answer (score 1):

When you are registering the .then() callback the context of the function changes.

In order to keep the context you can use the `bind` method.

```
methods: {
  get: function() {
    axiosInstance.get('/contactTemplate')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.items = response.data._embedded.contactTemplate
      }.bind(this)) // added .bind
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: i could try it tomorrow, the solution proposed by saurabh worked as expected

Answer (score 1):

vue-resource is now using `response.body` rather than `data` so look to update as follows:

```
methods: {
  get: function() {
    axiosInstance
      .get('/contactTemplate')
      .then((response) => {
        this.$set(this.$data, 'items', response.body._embedded.contactTemplate)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
}
```

I've also used arrow syntax to correct the scope of `this` and `this.$set` to ensure the data that you set is reactive.

If this still doesn't produce the desired result I'd confirm the data is correctly returning from the endpoint. Vue-resource has methods such as `response.json()` available if for instance the server responds with an incorrect content-type.

Comment: I have read an article that vue-resource might be abandoned per-say so I decided not to use vue-resource at this point, rest calls are done via axios https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4#.s2rc283t0