# How to setup express route res.json(data) object and display the response in vue $HTTP call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, vue-resource

[image]

Actual data in the collection
[image]

Using express:
Mongoose model with mongodb collections called "comments"

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Comment = new Schema({
title : String,
});
mongoose.model('comments', Comment);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

**My get route:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Comment = mongoose.model('comments');


/* GET form. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
Comment.find(function (err, comments) {
    res.json(comments);
});
});
```

**My front.html which using vue and vue resource**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js">  `   `</script>`
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script> 
<title>$http access to express route</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    <a href="http://localhost:1337"> Front page</a>
</h1>

<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items">
            {{ item.title }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({

        el: '#app',

        data: {
            items: []
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchData()
        },

        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                this.$http.get('http://localhost:1337/form')
                  .then(result => {
                      this.items = result.data
                  })
            }
        }

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comments is not showing in my vue tag. What is the proper way to access the Comment.find(err, comments) object that express send back? The vue resource $http is working when I use a test api like (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) but when I try to access my route localhost:1337/form  route, it doesn't show anything. Need someone with good knowledge with express routes, vue. I can't find any examples online that demo this in details. It seems that all tutorials online just skip this part.

Do I need to return the results in my route in a different format? Do I need to add the results to a var so I can access by the $http? Do I need to change my route in express?

If anyone with a live example. It would be great to post a link.

Comment: I can't find any comments array in your objects from the json you provided

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Vue.JS work with AJAX http calls?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882134/does-vue-js-work-with-ajax-http-calls)

Comment: @ – El_Matella It's not an array. comments is an object that the express response sends back.

Comment: What if you change this `this.items = result.data`, to this `this.items = result.json()` ? How your API looks like, do you even have it ?

Comment: @Belmin Hi Belmin, it didn't work.  When I do that I get 304 error in the console. I used.stringify(comments)too.

Comment: Okay, I think it's issue in your Node application.How your method that call /form endpoint looks like in express - the thing you are posted here, is just root endpoint.I think you have to response data as json in your express app.

Comment: @Belmin That makes sense. I changed the res.sendfile to res.json(comments) and now the /form is showing a json output. I loaded the vue html and it is showing two lines in the list (which I have in the comment collection) but not showing the ACTUAL data. I will post a jpeg shortly.

Comment: Okay, saw picture - Do you have vue dev tools extension installed ? What it says ? Are you sure that `item.comments` is correct key in template ? Could you paste here your JSON data ?

Comment: @Belmin      Big thank you Belmin. It's working. I changed the {{item.title}} in the html and it works. You helped me yesterday and today big time. Truly appreciate it.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear you get it working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at JSON data now, and see that you don't have comments propery in response.

Try change this:

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items">
            {{ item.comments }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

to this

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for="item in items">
            {{ item.title }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And you should see your your data, rendered on page.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your `this` is not pointing to correct scope, scope of this changes inside an `this.$http` call, so you just have to do something like following:

```
    methods: {
        fetchData() {
            var self = this
            this.$http.get('http://localhost:1337/form')
              .then(result => {
                  self.items = result.data
              })
```

You can also check my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40882183/1610034) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40959779/1610034).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it but it didn't work. It's the only issue not covered in any of the tutorials online. Someone post an express app with vue accessing the route using a $http.get would be super helpful.  If anyone willing to do that, it would be super helpful to all beginners out there.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.`this` should be okay in this case, and pointed to correct scope.

Answer (score 0):

The express route handle needs to return response in json format so write your route like this:

res.json(responseObject)

In your html Vue tag, follow the code in the example and just change the {{item.fieldname}} to display whatever field name you need to display.

Credit goes to @Belmin for this answer.