# Masonry is not a function

Tags: vue-component, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to use masonry in my application. Following is my component template.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <section class="section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row team">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 member" v-for="team in teamMembers">
                        <div class="team__item">
                            <div class="team__info">
                                <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
                                <small>{{team.title}}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                teamMembers: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getTeamMembers();
        },
        methods : {
            getTeamMembers : function() {
                this.$http.get('teamMembers').then(response =>{
                    // console.log(response);
                    if(response.data.status=200) {
                        this.teamMembers = response.data.teamMembers;
                        this.$nextTick(function() {
                            var $container = $('.team');

                              $container.masonry({
                                columnWidth: '.member',
                                itemSelector: '.member'
                              }); 
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get the following error whenever the view is getting rendered.

```
TypeError: $container.masonry is not a function
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can include a `script` like that in a single file component. I think you will need to install masonary via npm then require it in your main js file to give vue access to it.

Comment: you can't place a script tag like that in the middle of a single-file component

Comment: move your script tag to index.html and also try window.$('.team')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get vue component DOM element by [this.$el](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el). So you can do the following:

```
$(this.$el.querySelector('.team')).masonry({
                            columnWidth: '.member',
                            itemSelector: '.member'
                          });
```

But remember this is valid as long as your component is not a [Fragment Instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots) i.e. it has a single root HTML tag.

---

You many need to put following script line in index.html, so that it loads properly.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.1.1/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nope that did not work.. I am getting the same error. and I do have a single root html elem..

Comment: @Gagan are you sure scope of `this` is correct inside your `this.$http.get` block, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41093864/1610034)

Comment: yep - I have the correct ```this``` scope. I think its finding the correct element but that masonry is not loading properly which is why i am seeing that error...

Comment: @Gagan Are you able to include the script file correctly: `<script src="https://unpkg.com ...`