# How can I update a Vue app's or component's property in a promise call back?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to update a Vue property in a Firebase callback as follow, but it's not working. This code

```
methods: {
    sign_out : function(e) {
        this.item_count = 0
    }
}
```

works, but when the property is set in a promise callback:

```
methods: {
  sign_out : function(e) {
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      this.item_count = 0
    })
  },
```

How can I set a property's value in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "this" in Vuejs 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820258/using-this-in-vuejs-2-0)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your `this` in your callback is pointing to the wrong object. There are a few ways you can fix this.

1. Capture `this` in a closure.

   ```
   methods: {
     sign_out : function(e) {
       var self = this;
       self.item_count = 0
       firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
         self.item_count = 0
     })
   }
   ```
2. Use a fat arrow.

   ```
   methods: {
     sign_out : function(e) {
       this.item_count = 0
       firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => this.item_count = 0)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use bind().

   ```
   methods: {
     sign_out : function(e) {
       this.item_count = 0
       firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
         this.item_count = 0
       }.bind(this))
   }
   ```

Fat arrows will not work in all modern browsers yet, so only use them if you are compiling to es5.

Comment: Sometimes you want to slap JS in the face. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make a reference to this outside of the callback. Use the reference inside the callback to access the this on the intended object.

So try something like:

```
methods: {
  sign_out : function(e) {
  this.item_count = 0
  _this = this;
  firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
       _this.item_count = 0        
    })
 },
```