# Handling Google Geocode Callback Results to Vue JS Model

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Here's my issue... I have two selections for my user, use current location, or use a zip code. When the user selects a zip code I make a call to the Google geocode API and retrieve the central point for that zip code. I want to be able to put these coordinates into my Vue model and then execute a method within Vue called refresh which retrieves some data from my database and calls a function that sets up the map with markers and bounds. Since the callback function is decoupled from the model, I cannot seem to set the Vue properties, nor can I call the method. How do I handle the callback?

Please note that the refresh method works properly when using the selection for current location.

getLocation is called when the user selects "Current Location"

checkZip is called when the user selects "Use Zip Code"

```
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app-content',
        data: {
            locationType: "CurrentLocation",
            lat: "",
            lng: "",
            radiusInMiles: 10,
            filters: [],
            zipCode: "",
            geoError: "",
            error: "",
            results: []
        },
        methods: {
            getLocation: function () {
                this.zipCode = "";
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.storeLocation, this.locationError);
                } else {
                    this.locationType = "ZipLocation";
                    console.log("Geolocation does not appear to be supported by the browser.");
                    this.geoError = "Unable to obtain location. Please make sure location services are turned on and try again.";
                }
            },
            storeLocation: function (position) {
                this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
                this.refresh();
            },
            locationError: function (err) {
                this.locationType = "ZipLocation";
                this.results = [];
                console.warn(err);
                this.geoError = "Unable to obtain location. Please make sure location services are turned on and try again.";
            },
            refresh: function () {
                if (!(this.lat && this.lng && this.radiusInMiles && this.filters)) {
                    console.log("Location and filters are undefined.");
                }
                else {
                    //https://github.com/axios/axios
                    axios
                        .post('xyxyxyxyx', {
                            lat: this.lat,
                            lng: this.lng,
                            radiusInMiles: this.radiusInMiles,
                            filters: this.filters.toString()
                        })
                        .then(response => {
                            this.results = response.data.d;
                            //Send to map function...
                            loadMap(this.lat, this.lng, this.results);
                        })
                        .catch (error => console.log(error))
                }
            },
            checkZip: function () {
                if (this.zipCode.length == 5 && !isNaN(this.zipCode)) {
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'zipcode ' + this.zipCode }, function (results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            //Here's my issue...
                            //How do I store to the model and then call this.refresh
                            this.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                            this.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                            this.refresh();
                        } else {
                            console.error("Request failed.")
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by copying the Vue model into a variable (self).

[How can I update a Vue app's or component's property in a promise call back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590538/how-can-i-update-a-vue-apps-or-components-property-in-a-promise-call-back)

```
checkZip: function () {
    if (this.zipCode.length == 5 && !isNaN(this.zipCode)) {
        var self = this;
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': 'zipcode ' + this.zipCode }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                self.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                self.lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                self.refresh();
            } else {
                console.error("Request failed.")
            }
        });
    }
}
```